# Multiple tables with the same values in TOML

Tags: toml

I'm new to TOML and I have several sets of a scenario where two tables are identical. Is it possible to define multiple tables with the same keys without having to repeat everything?

For example, take this TOML file for AWS SAM configuration. When using the `sam local` commands, the options I require are exactly the same, but I have to define them twice.

```
version = 0.1

[dev1.local_invoke.parameters]
profile = "dev1"
...

[dev1.local_start_lambda.parameters]
profile = "dev1"
...

[dev2.local_invoke.parameters]
profile = "dev2"
...

[dev2.local_start_lambda.parameters]
profile = "dev2"
...
```

I've tried the obvious things, but they don't work. I've also looked at the [documentation](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#table) but there is nothing obvious, though as mentioned I'm new to TOML so I may be missing something.

```
[dev.local_invoke.parameters]
[dev.local_start_lambda.parameters]
...
```

```
[dev.local.parameters]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TOML files don't support this feature as a deliberate design choice. In fact, this was discussed in more detail in [issue #697](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/697).

It seems like the driving philosophy is that as soon as values in the TOML file refer to other values, it ceases to become a flat file and also becomes less readable.

As a workaround, you may be able to keep your TOML files thin-and-readable by consolidating the shared values up front and then having a separate program or script process the TOML file and delegate the repeat values.